# real time data analysis and chart

Tags: graph, phpmyadmin, data-analysis

Which is the best open source real time data analytics tool so that I can show the processed data in phpmyadminin front end in form of graph

Like the scores of the 5000 students are there and I want to show the performance of students relatively on basic of different scales.

Performance of each student in different sections of Test

Performance of all students in a particular section

Is there any tool that can get the data automatically from database and I can write various comparisions and show them in the front end in form of graph in ral time.. as soon as the new user gives the test the graph gets updated..on page refresh

The coding platform I used is PHP and Database is PHPMYADMIN

Thanks

Comment: I think your database is *MySQL* and the User Interface to manage your database is *phpMyAdmin*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your database is MySQL, PhpMyAdmin is a tool to administrate a database easily :)

If you want to get the number of student for each grade, you could write a query, for example with the MySQL COUNT() function, and then create a graph using a PHP library like http://jpgraph.net/ .

Hope this helps :)